# PlotStyle like ocean waves?

Tags: graphics, style, generative-art

I wonder how one can manipulate options like `PlotStyle`, `Lighting`, and `Specularity` to make the plot look like crystal ocean waves:
[image]
Example plot:

```
RegionPlot3D[z <= .3 Sin[3 x] + 1 && x <= 0,
 {x, -2, 1}, {y, -2, 1}, {z, 0, 2.5},
 PlotStyle -> Directive[RGBColor[.8, .8, 1, .5]], 
 Lighting -> {{"Directional", LightBlue, {{0, 0, 0}, {-1, -1, -2}}}},
 Mesh -> None, Axes -> None, BoxStyle -> Dashed,
 BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

Comment: I don't understand. What do you want to reproduce? The color? The shape?

Comment: @MarcoB I just want to imitate the color. (Too difficult to reproduce the shape) Any method including `Texture` is welcome!

Comment: I don't think *Mathematica*'s there yet. You could adjust the opacity and the normals for a surface, but the water-like appearance (caustics, reflections, etc.) is not something I believe is easily done with what we now have.

Comment: @J.M. Yes. Nevertheless, any improvement that moves the appearance one step closer to water is appreciated!

Comment: I wasn't kidding about "not there yet": `Plot3D[Sin[x + Sin[y]], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, BoundaryStyle -> None, Lighting -> "Neutral", Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 45, PlotTheme -> "Classic", PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.8, ColorData["Legacy", "PowderBlue"]]]]` or `Plot3D[Sin[x + Sin[y]], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, BoundaryStyle -> None, ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors", Lighting -> "Neutral", Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 45, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.6], PlotTheme -> "Classic"]`

Comment: @J.M. This is apparently nicer!

Comment: I might as well link to [this article](https://doi.org/10.1080/2165347X.2012.680854) in case someone gets inspired...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get a little bit of sparkling by using a high `Specularity` coefficient, but the result tends to look more like shiny plastic than water.

```
(* not a real ocean wave spectrum *)
f[x_, y_] := x/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2)

ocean = Module[{n = 256, x, spectrum, r},
   x = N@RotateRight[Range[-n, n - 2, 2], n/2];
   spectrum = Quiet@Outer[f, x, x];
   spectrum[[1, 1]] = 0.0;
   r = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {n, n}] + 
     I RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {n, n}];
   Rescale[Re[Fourier[r spectrum]]]];

ListPlot3D[ocean, PlotRange -> {-1, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[0.8, 0.9, 1.], Specularity[White, 200]}, 
 Lighting -> {{"Directional", White, {0, 0, 10}}}, Mesh -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Considering *Mathematica*'s limitations, this is pretty good.

Comment: This answer shows that shape is also important, as the same set of your style options, if applied to the original function in my question, only makes it look like some wavy plastic toy. In comparison, your plot is more like the surface of the ocean, which may get a better look if we remove the black boundary line and fill the region below the plotted surface with clear water. :)

Comment: @Sneeze, "if we remove the black boundary line" - add `BoundaryStyle -> None` to Simon's plot. "fill the region below the plotted surface" - and add `Filling -> Bottom` too.

Comment: Yes, getting a plausible shape helps a lot, because then the lighting calculation does the hard work. As noted, the spectrum I used isn't at all accurate but it gets the idea across. You can try varying the power in the denominator of `f` for different effects. Smaller values (eg 1.35) will give you a more crinkly surface, higher values (eg 1.65) will appear smoother.

Comment: Just wait long enough and water is going to look like shiny plastic, problem solved..

Comment: This ocean wave looks promising! I'll try putting it into [a proper render engine](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1810945) to see what comes out!

Answer (score 14):

Rotate it around and you'll see that *M* is "not there yet" as @J.M. notes. From just about any point of view, it cannot really model sunlight reflecting off the surface. (If *M* can, then I can't get it to.)

```
SeedRandom[0];
waves = With[{n = 20}, 
   MapThread[
     Sin[#1^4 First@RotationMatrix[#2] . {x, y} + #3]/(1 + #1^(8)) &,
     {RandomReal[{0.2, 2.4}, n], RandomReal[{0.3, 1.2}, n], 
      RandomReal[2 Pi, n]}] // Total
   ];
col = RGBColor[0.6, 0.9, 1.];
col2 = RGBColor[1., 1., 0.8];
Plot3D[waves, {x, 0, 18}, {y, 0, 18},
 PlotRange -> 8, PlotPoints -> 75,
 Mesh -> None,
 Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.2, col], 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[
   Specularity[col2, 100],
   Glow[Darker[col, 0.9]],
   Opacity[0.2],
   col],
 Lighting -> {
   {"Ambient", Darker[col, 0.35]},
   {"Directional", col2, {{15, 15, 15}, {0, 0, 0}}}},
 ViewPoint -> {-2.1473148110909985`, -1.9225307125696098`, 
   1.7728267713727204`}]
```

[image]

It does make me want to go to a nice, warm beach, though.

---

**Update**

One trick to get sparkle on a translucent plot is to set the opacity to 1 and then interpolate between the two images as a function of brightness.  One can only do this on `Image` once the lighting and view point are set, so the image cannot be rotated. (Got to work on the waves, some sort of combination of waves and @Simon's texture.)

```
SeedRandom[0];
waves = With[{n = 8, k = 2}, 
   MapThread[
      Sin[#1^4 First@RotationMatrix[#2] . {x, (2 y + Sin[#1^2 y/(1 + #1)])/3} + #3]/(1 + (#1 - 1/8)^(7)) &,
      {RandomReal[{0.7, 1.}, k]~Join~RandomReal[{1.5, 3.0}, n - 2 k], 
       RandomReal[{0.8, 1.2}, k]~Join~RandomReal[{1., 1.6}, n - 2 k], 
       RandomReal[2 Pi, n - k]}
    ]~Join~
     MapThread[
      Sin[#1^4 First@RotationMatrix[#2] . {x, (2 y + Sin[#1 y/(1 + #1)])/3} + #3]/(5/2 + (#1)^( 4)) &,
      {RandomReal[{1., 1.2}, k], RandomReal[{2.2, 2.6}, k], RandomReal[2 Pi, k]}] // Total];
col = RGBColor[0.6, 0.9, 1.];
col2 = RGBColor[1., 1., 0.8];
plot1 = Plot3D[waves, {x, 0, 18}, {y, 0, 18}, PlotRange -> 5, 
   PlotPoints -> 75, Mesh -> None, Filling -> Bottom, 
   FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.201, col], 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Specularity[White, 400], Glow[Darker[col, 0.9]], Opacity[0.2], col], 
   Lighting -> {{"Ambient", Darker[col, 0.35]}, {"Directional", col2, {30, 30, 20}}},
   AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
   ViewPoint -> {-2.1473148110909985`, -1.9225307125696098`, 1.7728267713727204`}];

img1 = Image@plot1;
img2 = Image[plot1 /. {Opacity[0.2] -> Opacity[1]}];

ixf = Compile[{{c1, _Real, 1}, {c2, _Real, 1}},
   With[{t = (1 - Sqrt@Abs[1 - (Norm[c2] - 1)]; (Norm[c2] - 1))^12},
    (1 - t) c1 + t*c2],
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True
   ];

Image[ixf[ImageData@img1, ImageData@img2], Options@img2]
```

[image]

Comment: This is more "swimming pool" than "beach", but still pretty good. ;)

Comment: @J.M. Thanks. Yeah, a beach would take caustics, and sand, and sea foam.

Comment: Appreciate the way you introduce sparkles! Nice texture, making it difficult to decide on which answer to accept.